# SDCAlertView not dismissing text field keyboards in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

"Manual" alerts work fine with text fields and dismiss keyboards when an action is clicked.

With `SDCAlertView` the text fields are not dismissed.

Have not updated to Swift 4. Kept everything as is. Only running on iOS 11.

Eg. from the demo project: http://file.5ep4r0.com/fAMsWuV.mp4

Thanks

Comment: After action clicked , do `alert.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: Thanks. Will try